# Use package.json script without yarn/npm command

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, yarnpkg

Is there a possibility to run `scripts` commands inside `package.json` file without having to type `yarn` or `npm` before? I mean I have something like:

```
 "scripts": {
    "get": "node index.js"
  }
```

so to run it I have to type `yarn get [arguments]`. Is there any way to type only `get [arguments]` and it will also work?

Comment: its just a json file. You can read it by any means. E.g.g. https://stedolan.github.io/jq/, or from a program such a node or python. Then you can pipe that command into a shell.

Comment: it seems you want install the module as global and [use the `bin` field](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/configuring-npm/package-json#bin)

Comment: it is basically only index.js file that I want to run by a simple command from terminal

Answer (score 0):

I believe these scripts are run off on npm / yarn shell-scripts, so you do need to call npm / yarn for it to know what to run.

Alternatively, you could extract these scripts out to a bash (.sh) file and execute the bash file. In your package.json, you can also link the script to just run the bash file.

Comment: it is basically only index.js file that I want to run by a simple command from terminal

Comment: For your simple case (`node index.js`) this should be fine, but it's worth noting that running `npm run get` also implicitly appends `./node_modules/.bin` to your `$PATH`, so if you pull it out into a separate shell script you may want to do that as well.

Answer (score 0):

**if you are not on windows this wont work but i am so im not sure how to do on any other os**
In windows you can just create a .cmd file called eg. "get.cmd" then in command prompt run
what it does is just run the file named "get" and it asks for the args then runs the file; it does not need the extension so its just "get"
"get" and it will run the content inside the file

package.json:

```
"scripts": {
   "get": "node index.js"
}
```

get.cmd: (this is windows batch)

```
# just to make it cleaner (you dont get it showing what was ran it just runs)
@echo off
# this is to get the args
set /p args="args: "
# then it runs the yarn with %args% because args was defined with the set /p
yarn get %args%
```

index.js: (this is just for example put your real file)

```
console.log("you ran index!)
```

In command prompt:

```
C:\users\*user*\*folder*> get
args: 123
you ran index!
```